# Where can I find an implementation of the wake-sleep algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, python, unsupervised-learning, resource-request, wake-sleep-algorithm

I'm looking to build from scratch an implementation of the [wake-sleep algorithm](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/ws.pdf), for unsupervised learning with neural networks. I plan on doing this in Python in order to better understand how it works. In order to facilitate my task, I was wondering if anyone could point me to an existing (open-source) implementation of this concept. I'm also looking for articles or, in general, resources that could facilitate this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following detailed and well documented [Python notebook](https://github.com/vadim0x60/wakesleep/blob/master/WakeSleep.ipynb), which uses only NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are looking for something in a library, but I've found [this](https://github.com/jackklys/wake-sleep-modifications/blob/master/wakesleep/ws.py) in a public Github (I've not checked deeply if it fits for you).

I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's definitely a start thank you! However it seems to build on tensor flow which is something I would like to avoid.